# Encode source code for a kivy distribution .apk

Tags: kivy

i've just recently began to develop using kivy for testing purposes and build the first .apk , so one question comes to mind.

The main.py contains source code that maybe i don't want to be "readable" if i want to distribute my apk... so is there a way to encode or hide my primary code when i create a .apk for google play store or as a normal linux app?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The .py is not shipped into the apk an the end, only the .pyo (Python Bytecode, optimized version, no docstring).
Still, bytecode can be reversed.

You could use [Cython](http://cython.org) to generate a C of your app (.pyx -> .c -> .so). All the main.py could do is:

```
from myencodedlib import run
run()
```

And you would have a myencodedlib.pyx that contain all the thing you want to compile into a binary C. (A side note, python-for-android need a recipe to compile python extensions. Look at the recipes/ directory to see how it's done for others.)

One last note, a .so is still decompilable for more advanced hackers. But then you would have a bunch of cpython call, with generated variables names. It would take severals hours to understand it. :)